# Moving WP installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP installed on a subdomain blog.domain.com. What do I have to do in order to get it moved into domain.com/blog directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice tut here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

I would suggest this approach: **Changing the URL directly in the database**

Also take a look at this SO answer:
[WordPress - moving from one host to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822531/wordpress-moving-from-one-host-to-another/2823000#2823000)