# How do I migrate a local WordPress site to a hosted server?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress site locally. When I'm all done, I want to FTP it to my remote hosting server.  I assume that I will need to recreate the MySQL database or perform an Export/ Import and I think I can handle that (although I'm open to any tips)... My main question is can I just copy all the files over (WP + Theme + custom files) to my live server without breaking the links?, because currently most of the links start with localhost/ ...

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Transfer all files to server

**Step 2:** update wp-config.php with new DB credentials

**Step 3:** update your DB by replacing "localhost/yourlocalfolder" by "yoursitename"

**Step 4:** Login to wp-admin -> go to settings->permalinks and save the permalinks option to rewrite the .htaccess file .

Thats it, Your site is live. :-)

Comment: Your "Step 3" will break URLs in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822531/wordpress-moving-from-one-host-to-another/2823000